# prove spanning tree removed a vertex without loss cinnectedness

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that in every connected graph $G$ on $n ≥ 2$ vertices, there is a vertex that can be removed without
destroying the connectedness of $G$.

Comment: welcome to math.se! We are happy to help out ... But would like to see some effort on your part. So: any thoughts about this problem?  Did you try to draw some graphs with a spanning tree?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to prove that there exist a $u\in V(G)$ such that the subgraph $G-u$ is still connected?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a cycle, remove a vertex from cycle. Otherwise the graph is connected without cycle, hence a tree, then remove a vertex of degree = 1( there is a vertex of degree 1 by Hanhshaking lemma).